# Sapply Function in R: NA Introduced by coercion, but I have only numeric values

Tags: r, file, input, na

for my project,I should do a Differential Expression Analysis with this dataset, where the rows indicates the patients and the columns indicates the genes. The first column `os event` denotes the survival (could be `0` or `1`). [image]

For the analysis, I should convert these into numerical value with the line of code `data=sapply(data,as.numeric)`, but I have the warning: `NA introduced by coercion`. Now, the real problem is that all values become equals to `NA` and I can't understand why, since the only strange value that I have is `0`. I tried to do the same with the following dataset (which seems pretty the same in terms of structure) and it works fine:
[image]

UPDATE: as suggested in the comments, I run the following command :

`dput(data)`, where `data` is my Dataframe. The output is this:

```
structure(list(os.event.RTK_RAS.NRF2.PI3K.WNT.HIPPO.CELL_CYCLE.MYC.NOTCH.TGF_Beta.TP53 = c("0;2;0;2.642857143;12.875;0;0;0;0;0;0", 
"0;1.72;0;5.071428571;7.5;0;4.25;0;0;9.333333333;5.666666667", 
"0;1.52;0;0;6.5;3.166666667;6.625;0;0;10.66666667;8.833333333", 
"0;0.88;0;1.928571429;6;2.25;0;0;0;0;0", "1;0.8;0;2.285714286;3.375;2.666666667;15;0;9.714285714;0;8.666666667", 
"0;1.4;0;0;13.375;0;7.625;0;0;0;10.16666667", "1;2.48;0;0;8.625;0;8.75;0;0;16.66666667;11.66666667", 
"0;1.08;0;0;7.875;2.25;6.125;0;5.428571429;0;8.166666667", "1;1.16;0;2;14.25;2.333333333;10.75;0;10.42857143;0;9.5", 
"0;1.56;0;0;14;0.8333333333;14;12;0;0;18.66666667", "0;0;0;0;3.875;0;4.75;0;0;8.666666667;6.333333333", 
"0;3.88;0;0;1.875;2.833333333;10.25;0;0;0;13.66666667", "0;7.76;17.5;2.785714286;0;7.583333333;7.875;0;0;0;10.5", 
"0;3.16;17.5;2.5;9;2.583333333;13.75;8.5;24.85714286;12.33333333;5.833333333", 
"1;2.36;0;4.857142857;5.75;3;0;0;0;0;0", "0;4.44;0;1.714285714;2.125;0;9;0;2.714285714;0;12", 
"1;1;0;2.214285714;4.25;2.583333333;5;0;0;0;6.666666667", "0;2.52;0;0;4.25;5.25;12;0;4.428571429;0;10.83333333", 
"0;1.08;0;2.214285714;7.125;2.583333333;0;0;11.28571429;0;0", 
"0;1.56;0;4.285714286;19.375;5;7.5;0;1.571428571;0;10", "0;1.08;0;1.571428571;8;1.833333333;0;0;0;0;0", 
"1;0.56;0;2.142857143;3.125;0;0;0;6.714285714;0;0", "0;0;0;0;2.125;0;5.5;0;0;0;7.333333333", 
"1;2.32;0;3.642857143;6.125;4.25;5.875;0;0;0;7.833333333", "1;0;0;7.714285714;14.875;9;6.5;0;0;0;8.666666667", 
"0;3.08;0;2.571428571;0;3;2.375;0;2.714285714;0;0", "1;1.48;0;0;7.5;0;5.375;0;0;0;7.166666667", 
"0;4;0;0;2.875;0;5.25;11.75;0;0;7", "0;2.88;0;1.428571429;3;1.666666667;0;0;0;9;0", 
"0;0;0;0;4.875;0;9.5;0;0;0;20.83333333", "1;4.12;0;2.642857143;4.25;3.083333333;6;0;0;0;8", 
"0;0;0;1.5;6.125;1.75;8.125;0;0;0;10.83333333", "0;1.56;0;0;7.25;0;4.25;0;0;0;5.666666667", 
"0;1.28;0;0.7142857143;8.75;0.8333333333;3.75;0;0;0;5", "1;5.56;0;0;5.375;0;8.75;0;7.285714286;0;0", 
"1;0.96;0;0;2.125;0;7.875;0;4.285714286;0;13", "0;2.76;0;12.21428571;6;14;6.25;0;6.142857143;0;8.333333333", 
"0;2.04;0;2.285714286;7.75;2.666666667;13.25;0;0;0;17.66666667", 
"0;1.28;0;1.285714286;0;0;8.125;0;0;15.33333333;10.83333333", 
"0;2.76;0;0;8.25;0;7;0;9.857142857;17.66666667;9.333333333", 
"0;0;0;0;6.875;0;8;0;8.857142857;0;10.66666667", "1;1.4;0;0;4.125;0;0;0;0;0;0", 
"1;1.24;0;0;2.125;0;2.625;0;6.571428571;0;3.5", "0;3.2;0;0.7142857143;3.875;4.333333333;0;0;0;0;0", 
"0;1.4;0;0;3.375;0;5.875;0;0;0;7.833333333", "1;1.52;0;3.357142857;5.5;3.916666667;4;0;2.857142857;0;5.333333333", 
"0;2.84;0;0;8.375;0;11.125;0;5.428571429;13;8.5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-47L))
```

Comment: could you do: dput(your_dataframe[1:10,]) and post it ihn your question?

Comment: yes, thank you @pbraeutigm. It gives me a vector. I am updating the question to upload the image

Comment: Please no image. Plain text. With this dput() we can test your data in R.

Comment: Sorry. I updated it with text. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. np. Seems like something went  wrong by reading your data into R. 
The data dosn't look like a proper dataframe. Thats why you get the NA error. R cant read over the columns, because there is only one column full of strings.
How did you get the data into R? Is this the whole output from dput() Usually I wpuld expect more info frpm R. Like structure(list(...

Comment: A more exhaustive output is given when I run the dput(data) command. I read the data with read_csv(). I am updating once more. Thank you for your time. Something about NA shows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253235/discussion-between-dylan-nico-and-pbraeutigm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data provided was probably imported in a weird way upstream. The dput() includes a list of character vectors that probably represent rows of a dataframe, with values separated by semicolons (`;`). I had to do some sequential data wrangling steps to get what I think is the desired output:

*You most likely have a better solution upstream, where the data is read-in/imported. I suspect the original data file was not actually a .csv file, but you imported the data with `read.csv`.
Try to find the correct data import function for your type of data, or use an agnostic function like `rio::import(file_name)`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

dat %>%  separate_wider_delim(delim = ";",
                              cols = everything(),
                              names_sep = ".",
                              ) %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    rename_with(~c("os.event", unlist(str_split(names(dat), "\\."))[-c(1:2)]))

# A tibble: 47 × 11
   os.event RTK_RAS  NRF2  PI3K   WNT HIPPO CELL_CYCLE   MYC NOTCH TGF_Beta  TP53
      <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1        0    2        0  2.64 12.9  0           0        0  0        0     0   
 2        0    1.72     0  5.07  7.5  0           4.25     0  0        9.33  5.67
 3        0    1.52     0  0     6.5  3.17        6.62     0  0       10.7   8.83
 4        0    0.88     0  1.93  6    2.25        0        0  0        0     0   
 5        1    0.8      0  2.29  3.38 2.67       15        0  9.71     0     8.67
 6        0    1.4      0  0    13.4  0           7.62     0  0        0    10.2 
 7        1    2.48     0  0     8.62 0           8.75     0  0       16.7  11.7 
 8        0    1.08     0  0     7.88 2.25        6.12     0  5.43     0     8.17
 9        1    1.16     0  2    14.2  2.33       10.8      0 10.4      0     9.5 
10        0    1.56     0  0    14    0.833      14       12  0        0    18.7 
# ℹ 37 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: I am trying to fix some warnings your commands give me. Your answer make sense, the input is for sure read in a strange way. You're right, the file is .xlsx. I will fix this, thank you.

Comment: I got warnings from a missing `as.is` argument in the call to `type.convert`. We can ignore it safely, otherwise include `as.is = TRUE`, as I just did in the updated answer.

Comment: please check if the suggested `rio::import` works. I strongly suggest you review the data import step over this post-import hacky solution